# How to collectively check whether bits are set in an unsigned integer?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Given an unsigned integer, I'd like to know if there's a way to determine whether multiple bits are set in a single operation. There's already an alternative way to do this by checking bit by bit (shown below), but I was wondering if there's a way to check all the bits collectively.

```
typedef enum Foo_X
{
  Foo_0 = 0x1,
  Foo_1 = 0x2,
  Foo_2 = 0x4,
  Foo_3 = 0x8,
} Foo_X;

bool CheckFoo ( UINT Value, Foo_X Foo_to_Check )
{
    if (Value & Foo_to_Check)
    {
        // Foo_to_Check is present
        return true;
    }
}

void main()
{
    UINT value = GetValueFromSomewhere();
    if (CheckFoo(value, Foo_0) && CheckFoo(value, Foo_3))
        // both Foo_0 and Foo_3 are present
    else
        // not both present
}
```

An example of using the collective method is shown below too. Any ideas? TIA!

```
bool CheckFooTogether ( UINT Value, UINT Foos_to_Check )
{
    // check value against Foos_to_Check collectively
}

void main()
{
    UINT value = GetValueFromSomewhere();
    if (CheckFooTogether (value, Foo_0 | Foo_3))
        // both Foo_0 and Foo_3 are present
    else
        // not both present           
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to return `false` if the check fails. Or, unless you're a proponent of extraneously superfluous verbosity, reduce the function body it to `return Value & Foo_to_Check;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

( Value & Foos_to_Check ) == Foos_to_Check

Answer (score 2):

```
(value & (FOO_0 | FOO_3)) == (FOO_0 | FOO_3)
```

returns `true` when `FOO_0` and `FOO_3` are both set.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple bitwise `and` check:

```
bool CheckFooTogether ( UINT Value, UINT Foos_to_Check )
{
    // check value against Foos_to_Check collectively
    if( (Value & Foos_to_Check) == Foos_to_Check)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    UINT value =  Foo_3 | Foo_2;
    if (CheckFooTogether (value, Foo_0 | Foo_3))
        // both Foo_0 and Foo_3 are present
        cout << "both present";
    else
        // not both present    
        cout << "not both present";
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/uEgQ4r)</kbd>